# jquery making a parent of a dynamic element clickable

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a span inside of a td.  I am able to make the span clickable, however I am having trouble making the parent clickable.

This works for the span

```
$(document).on('click', '.glyphicon-question-sign', function(){
          alert("test");
});
```

I am trying to get this to work for the parent, it does not.

```
$(document).on('click', '.glyphicon-question-sign:parent', function(){
          alert("test");
});
```

Here is the html that was dynamically created.

```
<td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign text-warning">
</span> Unavailable
</td>
```

Comment: What api did you read for the `:parent` selector?  As far as I'm aware, all selectors go down or sideways, not up.

Comment: @Taplar https://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/ . Obviously it is not working, but I am wondering if there is another way/

Comment: Which particular item should you choose?

Comment: @BlackStar1991 . I am trying to get the td element which is the parent of the span that has a class of glyphicon-question-sign

Comment: `:parent` doesn't do what you think it does.  `selector:parent` returns all elements that match `selector` and also *are* parents (i.e. they have children of their own), it doesn't return the parent of `selector`.

Comment: I just spent a few minutes in Fiddle to arrive at what @Barmar just posted: Parent does not do that thing you think it does. I did this: `$('.glyphicon-question-sign:parent').css("color","red")` which makes the text inside the `<span>` red (which you have no text there, but my fiddle did) but does not affect the text *outside* the span.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `:has()` selector to match a `td` that contains an element of the specific class.

```js
$(document).on("click", "td:has(.glyphicon-question-sign)", function() {
  alert("test");
})
```

```css
td {
  width: 100%;
  border: 5px solid #000;
}

span {
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <td>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign text-warning"></span>
  </td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("span").on("click", function() {
  $(this).parent("td").css("border-color", "yellow");
})
```

```css
td {
  width: 100%;
  border: 5px solid #000;
}

span {
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <td>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign text-warning"></span>
  </td>
</table>
```

I'm not sure I understood you correctly. I would do so

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to make the parent element clickable.  Not make a change to the parent when the child is clicked.

Comment: Never mind, I figure it out using the parent element to go to the first child instead of bubbling up from the child.  $(document).on('click', 'tr.warning td:first-child', function(){
          alert("test");
      });